# Display connectivity setting dialog on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, connectivity

How is it possible to trigger a connectivity setting dialog on Android like what's shown in the picture below?

[image: Connectivity setting dialog]

I suspect it's an Intent fired and not a custom API by One UI. `android.providers.Settings` class has some predefined Actions to open some settings pages but couldn't quite figure out which one to use to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Connect the phone to your PC. Do whatever you do to get this dialog to appear. Use the following command: `adb shell dumpsys activity activities`. This will show you all running tasks. You should be able to find the task with the settings `Activity` and you should be able to see the `Intent` that was used to open it. If you can't figure it out, edit your question and post the output of the command into your question and we can help.

Comment: The app in the picture is Spotify. Thanks for the tip. I didn't know you could watch that if the app wasn't in debug mode

Comment: Thanks so much, found the action to be `android.settings.panel.action.INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY`

Comment: If that helped I can create an answer for this question so that it may help others in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the phone to your PC. Do whatever you do to get this dialog to appear. Use the following command:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity activities
```

This will show you all running tasks. You should be able to find the task with the settings `Activity` and you should be able to see the `Intent` that was used to open it.

Comment: ```Intent { act=android.settings.panel.action.INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY flg=0x10800000 cmp=com.android.settings/.panel.SettingsPanelActivity }
          frontOfTask=true task=TaskRecord{bd5583b #4848 A=com.android.settings U=0 StackId=686 sz=1}``` was the intent. I actually found more detail on the android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Panel)

Comment: Unfortunately it was added in API 29